# What's happened to contact images in 5.8.2?

Tags: contact-image

I've recently upgraded a site to CiviCRM version 5.8.2, and my contact images are no longer visible on contact summary screens. If I click the Edit button the image is visible on the edit page.

Looking through the code for the summary screen the div that contains the image looks to be floated to the right of the contact name, and the URL for the image is certainly there, but nothing is visible on the page.

I've cleared caches and suchlike to no avail. Anyone got any clues as to how to make the contact images visible again?

Comment: What CMS is in use? If it's Drupal, what theme is in use?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7 in this instance. the Civi admin pages are displayed using the Adminimal theme, and I've also tried using the default Seven theme, which didn't change things. I've used Adminimal on this site for perhaps the last 12-18 months, during which time contact images have displayed as expected.

Comment: This seems to be working fine on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=203 though of course my mugshot may have been deleted by the time you check it

Comment: Thanks. And of course the fact that the demo site is running a different version of Civi and a different theme. I'll check what it like with Bartik.

Comment: On dmaster.demo.civicrm.org the div that contains the image is in a different place to my site. I've not edited that template. I'm wondering if an extension (I'm using Shoreditch for Mosaico for example) is messing with the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that that this problem wasn't caused by the update to 5.8.2 but instead the installation of the Shoredtich extension as part of installing Mosaico. This issue clarifies: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/issues/374

Essentially there is a JS file in the Shoreditch extension - contact-summary.js - that is loading on every page regardless of whether Shoreditch has been installed purely to support Mosaico (as in my case).